# Dispatch action when navigating on the same page with NgRx Router Store

Tags: angular, navigation, state, ngrx, ngrx-store

I am currently building an application using NgRx and the Router Store.
There is a dropdown in one component, that changes params in the url and navigates on the same component.
Since navigating on the same component doesn't call NgOnInit the corresponding effect (that calls the API) is not called.
In my opinion, the effect should always be called if component has changed the params.

```
loadTransactions$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
  ofType(
    NavigationActions.ActionType.NavigateToTransactionsSuccess,
    TransactionsPageActions.ActionType.LoadPage
  ),
  [...]
));
```

One idea I had, was to create a custom action that only listens to navigations on the component with the dropdown, but i have no idea how to do this.

My current solution is following:

```
this.store.select(RouterSelectors.selectUrl).subscribe(() =>
  this.store.dispatch(TransactionsPageActions.loadPage())
);
```

But this feels like it could cause some bugs in the future.
Is there any way to achieve this in a clean way?

Comment: Why not use `ActivatedRoute` from Angular itself and subscribe to changes?

Comment: @DanielB I would like to have a solution that works only through the effect and doesn't need extra logic in the component, because then i could just do the API calls in the component.

Comment: If you create a stackblitz I'll have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read the documentation more closely and the [effects guide](https://ngrx.io/guide/effects) tells you the following:

> **Note:** Event streams are not limited to dispatched actions, but can be any observable that produces new actions, such as observables from the Angular Router, observables created from browser events, and other observable streams.

So I implemented a custom router action and dispatch it in an effect, that is called when the accountId in the router store changes.

```js
accountIdChanged$ = createEffect(() => this.store.select(
   RouterSelectors.selectRouteParam('accountId')
).pipe(
   map((accountId) => RouterActions.accountIdChanged({accountId}))
));
```

Now I can listen to that action everywhere I want, for example in my transactions effect.

```js
loadTransactions$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
   ofType(RouterActions.ActionType.AccountIdChanged),
   // [...]
));
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you wanna control the loading of data via the route, it would be ideal and cleaner to perform the pulling of transactionData via routeGuards, specifically the `CanActivate` Guard

A simple snippet of a possible method can be seen below,

**routing.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
component: ShellPageComponent,
canActivate: [],
children: [

  {
    path: '',
    component: MainParentComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: ':transactionId',
        
        canActivate: [TransactionGuard],
            component:TransactionComponent
            
          },

 
          { path: '**', redirectTo: 'MainParentComponent' }
        ]
      },
     
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class  RoutingModule {}
```

**transaction-page.guard.ts**

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TransactionGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor( private store: Store<any>  ) {}

  canActivate(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> {
 

    const transcationId = route.paramMap.get('transactionId')
    //assuming  TransactionIsLoadedSelector is a selector to verify if transaction has been loaded and returns a Boolean

    return this.store.select(TransactionIsLoadedSelector$,{id:transcationId}).pipe(
      tap((TransactionIsLoaded)=>{
        if(!TransactionIsLoaded){
          this.store.dispatch(TransactionsPageActions.loadPage())
        }
      }),
      filter((TransactionIsLoaded)=> TransactionIsLoaded)

        
    )
  }

}
```